# How do I delay the loading of components until a constant is initialised

Tags: vuejs3

I have a Django and Vue application. A user will log in on the Django side and then there is a button that will take the user to the Vue part of the application where the Vue application will get the user data from the Django app based on the session details. The user data is then loaded into localstorage like so:

```
onBeforeMount(() => {
  if (localStorage.getItem("account") == null || store.changed == true) {
    axios.get("api/v1/users/current/").then((response) => {
      currentUser.value = response.data;
      let account = {
        id: currentUser.value.id,
        email: currentUser.value.email,
        role: currentUser.value.role,
        username: currentUser.value.username,
        upgraded: currentUser.value.upgraded,
        verified: currentUser.value.verified,
        profile: currentUser.value.profile,
        location: currentUser.value.current_location,
        loggedIn: true,
      };
      localStorage.setItem("account", JSON.stringify(account));
      store.changed = false;
    });
  }
});
```

The problem comes in when the header needs to load because it needs the data in localstorage (account) but it seems the header loads before the data in localstorage is available so I get an empty header because it needs the data from localstorage.

```
<template>
  <div class="header" id="header" v-if="account">

... all the rest 
</div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onBeforeMount, onMounted } from "vue";
import { useFoundersStore } from "@/stores/founders";
import Messages from "@/components/Messages";
const account = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("account"));

</script>
```

How can I delay the loading of the header component until the const 'account' has data in it?
The same applies for the user profile page because it also needs the data from localstorage('account')

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
onBeforeMount(async () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem("account") == null || store.changed == true) {
    try{
    let response = await axios.get("api/v1/users/current/");
    currentUser.value = response.data;
    let account = {
        id: currentUser.value.id,
        email: currentUser.value.email,
        role: currentUser.value.role,
        username: currentUser.value.username,
        upgraded: currentUser.value.upgraded,
        verified: currentUser.value.verified,
        profile: currentUser.value.profile,
        location: currentUser.value.current_location,
        loggedIn: true,
    };
    localStorage.setItem("account", JSON.stringify(account));
    store.changed = false;
    }
    catch(e){
       console.log(e)
    }
  }
});
```

I don't know why would you use '.then' like almost ever.

Comment: I tried it and it makes no difference. I have to refresh the page after logging in to see the header. Just so you know this is on my local pc so everything happens fast.

Comment: I added a delay to the components in the App.vue file and it seems to have fixed the issue. Can you tell me why you say one should not use .then pls?

Comment: You avoid promise hell. And in this scenario if something should be asynchronous you are effectively (at least I think) not waiting for the 'onBeforeMount' to end. It ends earlier, because the script runs forwards and then after some time it executes the 'then'. If you use await the onBeforeMount ends afterwards.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the explanation.